# How can I pass a Boost multi_array to a function?

Tags: c++, boost

I am trying to make that my arrays created with boost work with a function. I wrote the following code, but its not working. 
How can I make so, that my array is read by my functions? In the previous version of this code, I just defined my array like double U[N+1][4]. and it worked. What am I doing wrong while using boost?

```
#include "boost/multi_array.hpp"
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <time.h>

int const N=400;
int const x1=0;
int const x2=1;
int const gammaValue=1.4;

void Output(double U[N][3])
{
    double x,dx;
    dx=(double(x2-x1))/double(N);
    FILE *fp;
    double rho,u,p;
    fp=fopen("result.dat","w+");
    fprintf(fp,"%2.30s\n %20.60s\n %20.18s\t %2.3d\t %2.18s\t ","TITLE = \"1D-EULER.dat \"","variables = \"x\", \"rho\", \"u\", \"p\"","zone i=",N+1,"f=point\n");


    for(int n=0;n<N+1;n++)
    {
        x=x1+n*dx;
        rho=U[n][0];
        u=U[n][1]/U[n][0];
        p=(gammaValue-1)*(U[n][2]-0.5*U[n][0]*u*u);
        fprintf(fp,"%20.5f\t%20.5f\t%20.5f\t%20.5f\n",x,rho,u,p);
    }
    fclose(fp);
}

int main () {
    // 3 x 4 x 2
    typedef boost::multi_array<double, 2> array_type;
    typedef array_type::index index;
    array_type A(boost::extents[N][3]);

    int values = 0;
    for(index i = 0; i != N; ++i) {
        for(index j = 0; j != 3; ++j){
            A[i][j] = i+j;
        }
    }

    Output(A);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [multi_array](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/multi_array/doc/reference.html#multi_array_class)'s member function `data()`, it returns a pointer to the beginning of the contiguous block that contains the array's data. Once you get the address of the first element, you can get others since you already know the dimension of the array.

```
    double * p = A.data();
    double (*array)[3] = (double (*)[3])p;
    Output(array);
```

Comment: You mean Output(A.data());

Comment: then you just need a conversion as my answer shows.

Comment: In fact, make it a `static_cast<double(*)[]>(p)`

Comment: I'd prefer `reinterpret_cast<>()` since this kind of cast is so dangerous.

Comment: Using reinterpret_cast _makes_ it dangerous. It's the cast that tells the compiler "Shut up, I know what I'm doing". And it's semantics are, by definition, implementation defined.

Comment: Am i correct to say that for a 3D array, this can be implemented like this:

      `double ** p = A.data();
      double (**a)[3] = (double (*)(*)[3])p;
      double (*array)[3] = (double (*)[3])p;
      Output(array);`

Comment: Wrong! I check and I cant do it like that. How can you do it for a 3D Array? @jfly can you help me?

Comment: @heri-salmas. It's the same thing, just like this:`double * p = A.data();
 double (*array)[3][3] = (double (*)[3][3])p;
 Output(array);` Of course you also need change the definition of `Output()` as this: `void Output(double U[N][3][3])`

Answer (score 1):

Why not just change the signature of the Output function? Move the `array_type` typedef to the top of your file and then change the Output function to this:

`void Output( array_type& U )`

Or, better yet, make the parameter `const`. Here's some code:

```
#include <boost/multi_array.hpp>                                                                                                                                                                                                              
#include <iostream>                                                                                                                                                                                                                           

typedef boost::multi_array< double, 2 > array_type;                                                                                                                                                                                           

void Output( const array_type& arr )                                                                                                                                                                                                          
{                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
    std::cout << "here" << std::endl;                                                                                                                                                                                                         
}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             

int main( int argc, char ** argv )                                                                                                                                                                                                            
{                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
    array_type arr;                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    Output( arr );                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    return 0;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
}
```

This does nothing but demonstrate the principal of changing the function signature appropriately.

Comment: I am not sure if that works, @RobH ,  while doing it, the compiler tells me tha there is an assertion fail,

Assertion failed: (size_type(idx - index_bases[0]) < extents[0]), function access

Comment: The principal - changing the type of the parameter so that the array can be passed directly - is sound. A compiler error indicates that you're doing it wrong though, I'm afraid. The code in my edit above compiles cleanly.